# Python Groupby string

Tags: python, dataframe

I have my dataframe:

[image: dataframe]

I need to group by domains. To look something like this:

[image]

Tried to do it by groupby

```
GR = email1.groupby('domains')
```

but the result is only

```
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000017F26F28D90>
```

Also tried by count. It's close, but its not it.

```
GR = email1.groupby('domains').count()
```

[image]

Comment: You are not "grouping" anything. Just sorting it. Do `email1.sort_values(['domains', 'other_column'])

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `group_keys` parameter of the `groupby` function call. It should provide you the desired pattern. So, have this function call:

```
GR = email1.groupby('domains', group_keys=True)
```

Then you can try to `describe` the data frame that might give you the best case scenario. Do understand that data frame are intended to be used for numeric data only, so string processing will not have many features enabled here :)

```
GR.describe()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thank you. Maybe i wrote it little wrong. I need to have on index gmail.com, all gmails mails. Something like that. Trying for 3 hours and have no results :/ Thats why at first i had only one column, with full emails. Then i use it 

email1['domains'] = email1[0].apply(lambda x: x.split('@')[-1]) 

to get only domains. 

Not trying to make index of this domains.

Comment: Is it necessary that you use a dataframe? Why don't you get your data described in a primitive like `dict`? It will make this a lot easier! You can then use some `collections` functions, like `map` for instance?